# React useEffect missing dependecy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

Normally ı take a warning like that ,  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loadAllAbout'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I have code like that but when i give [loadAllAbout] also ı get a warning

---

Line 15:9:  The 'loadAllAbout' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 13) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'loadAllAbout' in its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

---

What i have to do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: [Please post code as text, not images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The warning is telling you pretty much exactly what you need to do. Seems like the best course of action here would be to put the `loadAllAbout` function in a `useCallback()`

Answer (score 0):

> What i have to do ?

Either one of the two things the error says, or just remove the function and put the logic that's in it directly into your `useEffect` callback, if you only ever use it from that callback.

Here's what the two options the error message gave you look like: Moving the `loadAllAbout` function into your `useEffect` callback:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...code using `loadAllAbout` (here or after it, either is fine)...

    function loadAllAbout() {
        // ...
    }
}, []);
```

Or using `useCallback` or similar to make `loadAllAbout` not a new function every time your component function runs:

```
const loadAllAbout = useCallback(() => {
    // ...
}, []);
```

Comment: **Note:** I haven't tried to read the code in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Because `loadAllAbout` is re-created on every render, adding it as a dependency will in fact cause your effect to run on every render.

The missing dependency warning can be safely ignored in some cases. Here, as your effect is only being run once to initialize some data, it should be fine.

If your component is going to re-render many times, memoizing `loadAllAbout` and including it as a dependency would be a more complete solution, but this may not be necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

**1. (Stopped working) Use function as useEffect callback**

```
useEffect(loadAllAbout, [])
```

**2. Declare function inside useEffect()**

```
useEffect(() => {
  function loadAllAbout() {
    ...
  }
  loadAllAbout()
}, [])
```

**3. Memoize with `useCallback()`**
In this case, if you have dependencies in your function, you will have to include them in the useCallback dependencies array and this will trigger the useEffect again if the function's params change. Besides, it is a lot of boilerplate... So just pass the function directly to useEffect as in `1. useEffect(loadAllAbout, [])`.

```
const loadAllAbout= useCallback(() => {
  ...
}, [])
useEffect(() => {
  loadAllAbout()
}, [loadAllAbout])
```

**4. Disable eslint's warning**

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadAllAbout()
}, []) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly what the eslint plugin suggests: move the function inside useEffect and you have a clean dependancy array. `loadAllAbout` is the kind of effect that's used once on mount, so useEffect is the perfect place for it.